# Can the mean of an empirical CDF be different than .5?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I was asked to convert a series of values into a series of percentiles corresponding to these values with respect to the empirical cdf constituted by the initial series.

Using R, I wrote:

```
toPercTS <- function(aSeries){
  ECDF <- ecdf(aSeries)
  percTS <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(aSeries)){
    percTS[i] <- ECDF(aSeries[i])
  }
  return(percTS)
}
```

The function `ecdf` returns the empirical cdf of a series. A detail surprised me:

```
> max(toPercTS(someSeries))
[1] 1
> min(toPercTS(someSeries))
[1] 0.00990099
> mean(toPercTS(someSeries))
[1] 0.5049505
```

The mean is slightly greater than .5 whereas I thought it would be exactly equal to 0.5, by construction. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You're thinking of the median I think and not the mean.

Comment: You may be expecting the ECDF to be symmetric (in a particular sense related to the intuition you're expressing), but since the proportion at or below an observation includes the point itself, it's not symmetric. You might be after something nearer the "cdf" values used to produce approximate expected order statistics (like those that would be given by `ppoints(sort(x))` while `qnorm(ppoints(sort(x)))` would be approximate normal order statistics). I found your first sentence impenetrable -- can you explain the underlying problem in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have data $x_1, \dots, x_n$ where each $x_i$ is an iid realization of some random variable $X \sim f$. Then the ECDF is
$$
\hat F_n(x) = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1(x_i \leq x).
$$

Your question is if $\frac 1n \sum_i \hat F_n(x_i) \stackrel ?= 0.5$.

Let's first assume that all of the datapoints are unique, and WLOG let's assume that they're sorted so that $x_1 < \dots < x_n$.

For some $i$, think about the sum $\sum_j \mathbf 1(x_j \leq x_i)$. Suppose $i=5$. Then we know $x_1 < \dots < x_4 < x_5 < x_6 < \dots < x_n$ so the first 5 terms of the sum are 1 and the rest are 0. In general, this sums counts the number of datapoints less than $x_i$, which since they are sorted and unique, is $i$. Putting this together, we have
$$
\frac 1n \sum_i \hat F_n(x_i) = \frac 1{n^2} \sum_i i = \frac{n+1}{2n}
$$

so it's very close to but not quite equal to 1/2 (in the continuous case).

If the $x_i$ are not all unique then this does not necessarily hold. Suppose have $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = x_3 = 2$. Then
$$
\frac 1n \sum_i \hat F_n(x_i) = \frac{1 + 3 + 3}{3^2} = \frac 79 \neq \frac{3 + 1}{2 \times 3} = \frac 23.
$$

An example in R (taking advantage of how the resulting elements of `x` are almost surely unique):

```
n <- 24
x <- rnorm(n)
e <- ecdf(x)(x)
mean(e)            # 0.5208333
(n + 1) / (2 * n)  # 0.5208333
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two numbers: 1 and 2. Then ecdf = 50% for 1 and 100% for 2. The mean of ecdf = 75%, instead of 50%. I guess if you add another data point with ecdf = 0, you will get mean ecdf = 50%.

Comment: Ecdf could not be equal to zero. I don't understand what do you mean by adding a point with ecdf equal to zero.

Comment: $F(-\infty) = 0$. Add this point to your dataset after ecdf calculation, you will get the mean of ECDF = 0.5, given there is no tided value, ie. $X_i \ne X_j$ for $i \ne j$. Without that point, the mean of ecdf = $\frac {n+1}{2n} > 0.5$. Adding that point, the numerator has no change, but denominator will +1, so the mean of ecdf = $\frac {n+1}{2(n+1)} = 0.5$

Comment: But the question is about estimating ecdf. By *evaluating* ecdf on arbitrary points you can get *any* mean, the same as evaluating non-empirical cdf, or literally almost any function evaluated on arbitrary points.

Comment: 1. ecdf = empirical cumulative distribution function = estimate of cumulative distribution function. You cannot estimate the estimate. 2. ecdf is a step function. In your dataset, only the jump points were saved (assume no tiers). From your program, you just calculated the mean of saved ecdf value, which is fixed at (n+1)/n given no ties. If non-empirical cdf means cdf, then cdf and ecdf are totally different for continuous random variable. ecdf is a step function, and cdf are a continue function.